# Split a Python string (sentence) with appended white spaces

Tags: python, string, split, whitespace

Might it be possible to split a Python string (sentence) so it retains the whitespaces between words in the output, but within a split substring by appending it after each word?

For example:

```
given_string = 'This is my string!'
output = ['This ', 'is ', 'my ', 'string!']
```

Comment: You are splitting, not splicing.

Comment: You don’t put any effort on writing some code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! :-)

Comment: This seems to be a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You may get more useful answers if you describe what you want to achieve, and add some context. See also [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I avoid regexes most of the time, but here it makes it really simple:

```
import re

given_string = 'This is my string!'
res = re.findall(r'\w+\W?', given_string)

# res ['This ', 'is ', 'my ', 'string!']
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

```
>>> given_string = 'This is my string!'
>>> l = given_string.split(' ')
>>> l = [item + ' ' for item in l[:-1]] + l[-1:]
>>> l
['This ', 'is ', 'my ', 'string!']
```

Comment: It preserves spaces count e.g. double spaces

Comment: Can we use a regular expression instead? To accommodate any number of spaces

Answer (score 0):

just split and add the whitespace back:

```
a = " "
output =  [e+a for e in given_string.split(a) if e]
output[len(output)-1] = output[len(output)-1][:-1]
```

the last line is for deleting space after thankyou!